# simple html dom load_file returns array

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I have a weird problem. I've been using Simple Html Dom library for a while now, but trying to load a certain page always returns content in an array, and not HTML. I'm stumped.

This is the code:

```
$target_url = "https://www.bol.com/nl/p/foscam-fi9928p-1080p-ptz-dome/9200000075190022/prijsoverzicht/";
    $html->load_file($target_url);
    echo "$html";
```

I've also tried `file_get_contents` and `file_get_html`, as wel as tried with a cURL library; they all return an array. 
Also it only appears to happen on these overview pages, not on product pages themselves.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that bol.com returns JSON.

```
  Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Where do you find the content-type of that page? Also do you happen to know if there's a way I can request the page without the content-type being json?

Comment: I did a "wget -S" of your URL, one of the headers was "Content-Type".  No, you can tell bol what you accept as content-type, with the "Accept" header, as in "Accept: text/html", and they will return HTML.  Others might not be so kind.